# Objective c customizing EKEventEditViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ekevent, ekeventkit

I am displaying event edit View using this code

```
-(void)editEvent:(EKEvent *)events{

          EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    addController.delegate = self;
    addController.eventStore = [SharedEventStore defaultEventStore];
   addController.event = events;

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  objectForKey:KCalendarIdentifier]];

    addController.editViewDelegate = self;
    addController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:addController animated:YES completion:nil];


    [addController release];


}
```

Now my Requiremet is to disable the title of Event in that View, i mean i do not want the user to be able to edit the title of event inside EKEventEditViewController view, but i can't figure it out from long time, plz. guide me in this Thanx and Regards.

Comment: This is not possible. If you want that functionality you have to create your own viewController for editing events.

Comment: @Saad Umar : Have you accomplished this task.